# difference between 虚実 and 真偽

Tags: meaning, synonyms

It seems like 真偽 and the second meaning for 虚実 have the same meaning, but are there any differences in how they're used?

> 真偽
> **真実と、いつわり。まことかうそか。「真偽のほどはわからない」**
>
> 虚実
> １ 実質・実体のあることとないこと。　　
> **２ うそとまこと。虚構と事実。「虚実とりまぜて語る」**　　
> ３ 「虚虚実実」の略。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 真実と、いつわり。まことかうそか。「真偽のほどはわからない」

On this one, you are saying you cannot conclude if a thing is true or false.

> ２ うそとまこと。虚構と事実。「虚実とりまぜて語る」

On this one, you are mixing up fiction and fact. It might imply exaggerating, a made-up story and so on.